# IIS 7.0 REST Web Service 404 error

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, iis-7

I have a REST C# web service that runs fine under IIS 6.0 and IIS 7.5 but for some reason I get a 404 when running under IIS 7.0.

The path to my dll is as follows: wwwroot\PHSendMessage\bin\PHSendMessage.dll

My web.config is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add type="Service, PHSendMessage" verb="*" path="Request" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The class that inherits from IHttpHandler is named Service and this class contains the ProcessRequest function.

I am attempting to run the following url: `http://localhost/PHSendMessage/Request?xml=hello`

The above URL should call the get method and return the value from the "xml" parm to the screen, but I get a 404 error instead.

Everything I have read seems to point to the handler is not found, or not routing to my DLL correctly. I am not sure if the Web.config needs to have additional entries that are not required in IIS 7.5.

I have tried to follow numerous guides to adding the handler mapping but always the unhelpful 404 error. When following said guides I enter the Path and type similar to how I entered it in the web.config above and I may not be entering those correctly as I do not fully understand how these httpHandlers route to my dll.

Edit: I followed the following example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112470/Developing-a-REST-Web-Service-using-C-A-walkthroug

I also followed their link to 404 errors. The source code from the above link is also results in the same 404 error.

Has anyone had similar issues?

Comment: does the path http://localhost/Request?xml=hello work?

Comment: I migrated this over earlier.  I did my best with the tags, but I'm not very familiar with this area.